# How long does it take to transfer between Frankfurt Airport's terminals?

Tags: transit, short-connections, fra

I'm considering booking two flights on separate tickets through Frankfurt Airport. How much time should I include for a transfer between the terminals 1 and 2?

I will be flying Schengen to non-Schengen, with luggage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just took one yesterday, and it took me 15 minutes.

If you use the free official airport shuttle running outside (which you have to do since you have luggage), it will take you up to 30 minutes, from the point you left the doors of terminal 1 to the point you entered the door of terminal 2.

The official stated transfer time is 7 minutes, but it only covers the shuttle driving time. The shuttle will not leave immediately once you arrive to its stop, and you might need to wait for the shuttle. It also makes intermediate stop on a bus station - usually nobody boards/leaves there, but if people are, this could add 2-5 minutes to your trip.

PS. Terminal 1 and 2 are defined by the airlines, not the flight Shenghen status. For example, Lufthansa flies from Terminal 1 both to LAX (Z gates) and to Hamburg (A gates). So if you're flying Lufthansa on separate tickets, you might not need to change terminals at all.

Comment: What about the AirTrain? Or is it for airside transfers only?

Comment: You mean Skyline? Yes, it is gates-to-gates https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/flights-and-more/terminal-transfer/terminal-maps.html - the regular trains outside (Frankfurt Flughafen) don't go between T1 and T2, only T1.

Comment: Skyline is not only airside, it has coaches for both airside and landside passengers. So you can either use the bus shuttles or Skyline to switch between terminals.

Comment: "it has coaches for both airside and landside passengers" - can you go landside-landside there, or only airside-landside? And do you know where is its entrance? I haven't seen it in terminals, and even on a map it shows as only being past security. If it does go, it should be a better option than bus shuttle.

Comment: @GeorgeY. You can go landside–landside but you can only use two stops (terminal 2 and the central stop of terminal 1). In terminal 2, the landside station is on the top floor of the road-facing side of the terminal, bang in the middle. In terminal 1, it is also pretty centred in the B check in area and there are signs but it is slightly harder to find. The stations for A gates and C gates are airside only (and I believe non-Schengen only).

Answer (score 3):

A relative of mine did this exact trip: transiting FRA from a non-Schengen country to a Schengen country **on separate tickets with luggage**, switching between Terminal 2 and 1. **Gate-to-gate** it took only **70 minutes**, including passport control and the bus ride between the terminals. So if you're planning on making a similar trip, I'd say 2 hours should be plenty of time.